# How to use qflll() in the PARI library?

Tags: python, cygwin, pari, mathematical-lattices

I wanted to use the function `qflll` from the PARI library in python, so I downloaded `pari-python-cygwin-0.1.zip`, however when I attempted to use `qflll` in python, i.e.

```
qflll([[1,0,0],[0,1,0],[0,0,1]])
```

I got this error message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: Too few parameters provided: 1
```

So I how do I invoke the function `qflll` in python properly without any error?

Comment: Can you post what you did to cause the error?

Comment: @Banana: Hi, I have edited my code to your question.

Comment: Try `qflll(pari([[1,0,0],[0,1,0],[0,0,1]]).Mat())`.

Comment: @Banana: Hi it still cannot work.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in [these docs](http://www.math.ucla.edu/~jimc/mathnet_d/sage/reference/sage/libs/pari/gen.html#sage.libs.pari.gen.gen.qflll), the `qflll` function takes a PARI matrix as input. Therefore, you have to do something like:

```
sage: M = Matrix([[1,0,0],[0,1,0],[0,0,1]])
sage: p = pari(M)
sage: p.qflll()
[1, 0, 0; 0, 1, 0; 0, 0, 1]
```

Or, if you prefer, one sentence:

```
sage: pari(Matrix([[1,0,0],[0,1,0],[0,0,1]])).qflll()
[1, 0, 0; 0, 1, 0; 0, 0, 1]
```